# System.setProperty("java.version", "1.6") not working Android 5

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, mvel

I was using this command on Android 4 and it was working without any problem: 
`System.setProperty("java.version", "1.6");`
but when I upgrade my Android to 5 I start getting this error:
`Ignoring attempt to set property "java.version" to value "1.6"`

I want to set this property to 1.6 because I am using mvel library and this library checks this value inside it to do some logic, I don't want to modify the source of library to handle this problem, so How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't tested, but [as API Reference says](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), it could be **read only property** then you can not do that.